# Интерфейс доступа к реляционным БД в питоне (что имеет в виду Марк Лутц?)

Tags: python, база-данных

В книге **Марка Лутца** *"Изучаем Python"* есть такой фрагмент:

> В языке Python имеются интерфейсы
> доступа ко всем основным реляционным
> базам данных – Sybase, Oracle,
> Informix, ODBC, MySQL, PostgreSQL,
> SQLite и многим другим. В мире Python
> существует также переносимый
> прикладной программный интерфейс баз
> данных, предназначенный для доступа
> к базам данных SQL из сценариев на
> языке Python, который унифицирует
> доступ к различным базам данных.
> Например, при использовании
> переносимого API сценарий,
> предназначенный для работы со
> свободной базой данных MySQL,
> практически без изменений сможет
> работать с другими системами баз
> данных (такими как Oracle). Все, что
> потребуется сделать для этого, –
> заменить используемый низкоуровневый
> интерфейс.

Однако на последующих страницах про работу с СУБД больше ничего не сказано, разве что в заключении Лутц пишет:

> Если база данных должна хранить
> большой объем данных или эти данные
> имеют большое значение, мы могли бы
> отказаться от использования модуля
> shelve и использовать более
> полноценный механизм хранения данных,
> такой как ZODB (свободно
> распространяемая,
> объектно-ориентированная база данных,
> ООДБ), или более традиционную
> реляционную базу данных, такую как
> MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL или SQLite.
> В состав Python уже входит поддержка
> встраиваемой системы баз данных
> SQLite, однако в Сети вы найдете
> и другие свободно распространяемые
> альтернативы. Механизм ZODB, например,
> своими особенностями напоминает модуль
> shelve, однако в ZODB отсутствуют
> многие ограничения, присущие shelve;
> он поддерживает возможность работы
> с большими базами данных, параллельное
> изменение данных, транзакции
> и автоматическую сквозную запись
> изменений, выполняемых в памяти. Базы
> данных SQL, такие как MySQL,
> обеспечивают инструментальные средства
> по организации хранилищ данных уровня
> предприятия и могут напрямую
> использоваться из сценариев на языке
> Python.

Собственно, меня интересует, о каких интерфейсах доступа к реляционным базам данных говорит Лутц в начале своей книги. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Python "из коробки" уже способен, скажем, подключиться к БД и получить оттуда данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо речь идёт об этом - [Python Database API Specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). Суть в том что ваша программа на python независимо от того с какой СУБД работает может использовать единый интерфейс. Из коробки в python есть реализация только SQLite, для других БД надо ставить сторонние библиотеки, но ваш сценарий в плане доступа к БД не изменится. Например для использования MySQL надо установить - [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4).

Comment: О! Так гораздо понятнее. В MySQL-python мне не понравилось отсутствие поддержки Python3. Поэтому решил все-таки остановиться на [MySQL Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html).